# Evaluation Criterion for Google Sheets/Excel

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use sheets to solve the average based on specific criteria. 
I've used the `AVERAGEIFS()` to solve it out but I can't seem to get the appropriate criteria.

Here is what I've been doing:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Average_Range,Criterion1_Eval_range,AND(IFNA($A1,FALSE),NOT($A1=0)),Criterion2_Eval_range,IF(REGEXMATCH($D1, "Work"), TRUE, FALSE))
```

As you can see, my evaluation criteria are:

```
AND(IFNA($A1,FALSE),NOT($A1=0))
IF(REGEXMATCH($D1, "Work"), TRUE, FALSE)
```

I want to get cells in col A that are not 0 nor N/A and I need the REGEX of col D that has the word work in them.
I have also been wondering about how to get only even values. `MOD(cell, 2)=0` as a criterion.

I think the problem is in the criterion. The overall answer is a div/0 since no cells evaluate as true. I think the `$D1` and `$A1` are not switching for every line.

In this [Sheets Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGPxS.png) the desired output would be 38. (Last col, last row)

In the image, I want to get the average of all numbers if Column 1 is an even number over 5. To match my specific question, Add a column with the text "yes" for even numbers and "no" for odd. Use regex to determine if the number should be included in the average.

Edit: [Additional Info]

Data:
`10, home,, 35, work,, 763, office,, 4, work,, 7345, work,, 74, office,, 65, home,,n/a, work,,0, work,,`

Basically, there exists a value and an associated keyword. The average must only be for the values of one word. The values are ordered due to other restrictions.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0, I've edited

Comment: Can you please provide a sample which allows to test out the conditions like the regex expression you are using ?

Comment: `10, home,,
35, work,,
763, office,,
4, work,,
7345, work,,
74, office,,
65, home,,`
Basically, there exists a value and an associated keyword. The average must only be for the values of one word. The values are separated in their order due to other restrictions @Aerials

Comment: you can add `n/a, work,,0, work,,` to trigger the non-regex restrictions

Comment: Please edit your question with the extra information you added in the comments to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following construction of `AVERAGEIFS` together with `ARRAYFORMULA` get you the desired result.

For your sheet example the following formula will result in 38.

> `=AVERAGEIFS(B2:B9,ARRAYFORMULA(ISEVEN(A2:A9)),"true",ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A9),">5")`

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vwqo.png)

Answer (score 0):

try dropping the `IF`

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Average_Range, 
 Criterion1_Eval_range, 1=(IFNA($A1, FALSE))*(NOT($A1=0))), 
 Criterion2_Eval_range, REGEXMATCH($D1, "Work"))
```

Comment: It doesnt work. I think the problem is in the criterion format. I dont think it checks each individual `$D1`, `$A1`.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output